# customize devise registration route to accept :invite_token as a part of URL in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, routes

I would like to customize the devise registration routing path to accept and optional :invitation_token at the end of it.

for example

the incoming url would be

```
http://mywebsite.com/tenants/sign_up/kEjte
```

this would use the invitation code to set some hidden attribute fields.

if there is no invitation code, then it defaults back to original behavior

I have already overriden the registration controller with my own RegistrationsController.rb

here is my routes

```
  devise_for :tenants  ,:controllers => { :registrations => "registrations" }
```

here is my raked routes

```
 new_tenant_session GET    /tenants/sign_in(.:format)                           devise/sessions#new
          tenant_session POST   /tenants/sign_in(.:format)                           devise/sessions#create
  destroy_tenant_session DELETE /tenants/sign_out(.:format)                          devise/sessions#destroy
         tenant_password POST   /tenants/password(.:format)                          devise/passwords#create
     new_tenant_password GET    /tenants/password/new(.:format)                      devise/passwords#new
    edit_tenant_password GET    /tenants/password/edit(.:format)                     devise/passwords#edit
                         PATCH  /tenants/password(.:format)                          devise/passwords#update
                         PUT    /tenants/password(.:format)                          devise/passwords#update
```

cancel_tenant_registration GET    /tenants/cancel(.:format)                            registrations#cancel
         tenant_registration POST   /tenants(.:format)                                   registrations#create
     new_tenant_registration GET    /tenants/sign_up(.:format)                           registrations#new
    edit_tenant_registration GET    /tenants/edit(.:format)                              registrations#edit
                             PATCH  /tenants(.:format)                                   registrations#update
                             PUT    /tenants(.:format)                                   registrations#update
                             DELETE /tenants(.:format)                                   registrations#destroy

I haved read through the wiki articles on Devise, but i cant figure it out. 
Can anyone lend me a hand?

EDIT*

Okay, So I made some changes to the routes

here is the revised routes

```
  devise_for :tenants  ,:controllers => { :registrations => "registrations" }


  devise_scope :tenants do
    get "/tenants/sign_up/:invitation_token" => "registrations#new"
  end
```

and here is the raked routes

```
tenant_registration POST   /tenants(.:format)                                   registrations#create
 new_tenant_registration GET    /tenants/sign_up(.:format)                           registrations#new
edit_tenant_registration GET    /tenants/edit(.:format)                              registrations#edit
                         PATCH  /tenants(.:format)                                   registrations#update
                         PUT    /tenants(.:format)                                   registrations#update
                         DELETE /tenants(.:format)                                   registrations#destroy
                         GET    /tenants/sign_up/:invitation_token(.:format)         registrations#new
```

It seems like the route now accepts the invitation token, but when i type something like

```
http://localhost:3000/tenants/sign_up/KjEid
```

Devises gives me the following error

```
AbstractController::ActionNotFound at /tenants/sign_up/KjEid 
Could not find devise mapping for path "/tenants/sign_up/KjEid".This may      happen for two reasons:
```

What gives? why wont it accept the token parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, it suppose to be

```
  devise_for :tenants  ,:controllers => { :registrations => "registrations" }


  devise_scope :tenant do
    get "/tenants/sign_up/:invitation_token" => "registrations#new"
  end
```

I had `devise_scope :tenantS do`

before, that is why devise was complaining

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code snippet. I assume you have the code in your registrations controller new action to control the new parameter.

```
devise_for :tenants  ,:controllers => { :registrations => "registrations" }  as :tenants do
    get 'sign_up/:invite_key' => 'registrations#new'
    get 'sign_up' => 'registrations#new'
end
```

Comment: hmm that didnt work.. based on your suggestions I made some edits, and it now recognizes a invitation key, but now its returning `Could not find devise mapping for path`. I have made some edits in my original post